# My Remote Desktop Error connection is in my side or in the remote host? [CredSSP sugestion]

Tags: remote-desktop

I trying to connect with Remote Desktop Connection to other computer.

In my side I have Windows 10 (up to date), FortiClient 5.6.6.

In the other side I have Windows 8.1 (up to date)

With my phone and the same password I can connect to the Windows 8.1 (with Fortinet for Androids and Remote Desktop).

I try connecting from two others computers and I can’t.

The message I received is:

```
An autentication error has ocurred.
The function requested is not supported

Remote computer 192.168.0.99
This could be due to CredSSP encryption oracle remediation.
For more information, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866660
```

What can I try?

Where Is the problem? In my computer or in the remote computer?

[image]

Comment: Have you read the support article?

Comment: Configure the server to Vulnerable per the support article and then test your clients, if it works, you know you have to update your clients.